# Trap cursor in Window

Tags: c++, windows, camera, mouse, directx-11

I wrote my own cameraclass in C++ using DX11.
At the moment I use WM_MOUSEMOVE events to look around in the scene. To prevent the cursur to get out of the window, I call the function SetCursorPos to center the mouse whenever a WM_MOUSEMOVE event occurs.
But if I move my mouse very fast, the cursor gets out of the window.
A solution to that was using the function ClipCursor, but this leads to falter the rotation of the camera when the cursor hits the border of the rect. So ClipCursor solved the original problem, but ended in another.

Do you guys have any solution to that?

Comment: Would `SetCapture` help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regular windows message are not the best solution to drive precise controls. They inherit from the OS acceleration system, clipping and depends on other shenanigans as you can see.

The best API to receive mouse inputs is Raw Input. It has the advantage to expose the better dpi and polling rate the hardware can provide and is free of any under the hood manipulation. Once you read the mouse with this, you are free to use SetCapture and clipCursor to prevent unwanted click to an other window.

You can find the documentation here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645536(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 8):

For a Windows desktop app, just use [ClipCursor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648383.aspx) giving the rectangle of your window:

```
    RECT rect;
    GetClientRect(mWindow, &rect);

    POINT ul;
    ul.x = rect.left;
    ul.y = rect.top;

    POINT lr;
    lr.x = rect.right;
    lr.y = rect.bottom;

    MapWindowPoints(mWindow, nullptr, &ul, 1);
    MapWindowPoints(mWindow, nullptr, &lr, 1);

    rect.left = ul.x;
    rect.top = ul.y;

    rect.right = lr.x;
    rect.bottom = lr.y;

    ClipCursor(&rect);
```

Be sure to have a way to escape this mode so that users can choose to interact with other windows if desired. Typically you call `ClipCursor(nullptr);` when you go to a 'pause' menu to get out of 'mouse-look' behavior like this.

You can use "raw" input in desktop apps as well, see [Taking Advantage of High-Definition Mouse Movement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee418864.aspx). Keep in mind that raw input works pretty well for relative-movement 'mouse-look' behavior, but (a) it won't work over remote desktop, and (b) you won't get 'pointer-ballistics' which is a non-linear movement rate that makes a mouse more agile so you should generally stick with traditional `WM_MOUSE` messages when dealing with absolute-movement.

> For Universal Windows Platform, you can't use "raw" input as there's no equivalent to `WM_INPUT`, but you do get high-precision data out of the `MouseDevice.MouseMoved` event via the `MouseDelta` property. You don't need to use `ClipCursor` for relative movement in UWP, just turning off the cursor by setting the `CoreWindow.PointerCursor` property to nullptr will prevent the system mouse position from being tracked. Again, you should restore the system cursor when you are in a 'pause' menu. See [Developing mouse controls (DirectX and C++)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh994925.aspx).

See *DirectX Tool Kit* [Mouse](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Mouse) helper class and more importantly the [implementation](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/blob/master/Src/Mouse.cpp) file. For relative mode, it makes use of both `ClipCursor` and `WM_INPUT` for the Windows desktop Win32 implementation.